# How to run Stylecop only in check in?

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

I've to use Stylecop with VS2010 (using Team Developer) in my company, but it makes me waste a lot of time, and it's really anoying.

Does anybody knows how to run Stylecop only before checking in the code, instead of in every time I build the project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you checking your code into?  What source control?  TFS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using TFS.
I was just trying to avoid changing the project, so that I don't have the risk to commit it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you – I don't think it's helpful to run Stylecop on every build.

By default, Stylecop *doesn't* run when you build; it will only do so if your Visual Studio project has been deliberately [set up to make this happen](http://alandean.blogspot.com/2010/06/run-stylecop-on-every-build.html). So you'll have to edit your project to take this step out (and take care not to check your modified project in to source control).

Comment: That what I was avoiding to do. It can end up being commited.

Comment: It's good practice to "diff" changed files against the configured version before committing them. If you find you're checking things in accidentally then you have bigger problems.